# Highest Modify Date Among Multiple Tables

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, etl, delta

We have a frequent issue we encounter during ETL that I'm hoping someone here has solved before.  Assume we have three hierarchical tables: header, detail, and transaction.  The source system could update a record in any one of these, and will only update the last modified date of the table they changed.  When we run ETL, we need to pull all headers and all their details and transactions if any of the levels changed.

Across rows, we can use a max function, but for columns, is there an easy way to return the highest date of three separate columns?  We could do it with a nested case statement, but that gets messy when you have 7+ tables involved.  A DB agnostic approach would be great, but we are using Azure / SQL Server.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Some research came up with the below solution that seems to work for Azure.  We haven't tested the performance, but it's the best we've found so far.  I still welcome any suggestions as to alternatives or a better approach:

select
A.Date1, 
A.Date2, 
A.Date3, 
(SELECT MAX(DateAlias) FROM (VALUES (A.Date1), (A.Date2), (A.Date3)) T (DateAlias)) AS LatestDate
from TableName A;

Comment: Actually, just from your questions, we can not get what the really things you want to do. What's the table data look like and what is the output data you want. I'm glad to hear you have found the better solution. Just try it and you could post the answer by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Some research came up with the below solution that seems to work for Azure. We haven't tested the performance, but it's the best we've found so far. I still welcome any suggestions as to alternatives or a better approach:

```
select 
A.Date1, 
A.Date2, 
A.Date3, 
(SELECT MAX(DateAlias) FROM (VALUES (A.Date1), (A.Date2), (A.Date3)) T (DateAlias)) AS LatestDate 
from TableName A;
```